# How can I mine a transaction in a block with a specified timestamp in Hardhat?

Tags: hardhat

I'm working with time-dependent logic. In order to test it, a specific transaction needs to be mined at a specific time given in seconds.

In Hardhat it is possible to increase the block timestamp to the desired value. However I can't get the transaction to appear in that block (it's a few seconds off). Is there a way to configure Hardhat to include the transaction in a block with the exact specified timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to have some delay as the network logs your tx/contract. The best you can do is approximate this delay, and set your desired block timestamp including tolerance to trigger the tx.

Comment: I see. However since the Hardhat network is used exclusively for testing, I assume there is a way to set the block timestamp to the desired value. Is this not a possibility?